# What is the best approach to merge two objects in list in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I have a below list where `LineId` can be same. In such cases, I want to merge them where they are common. i.e., if `LineId` is same then sum up `Price`, `Total`, `AccountingTotal` and merge `Description` text.

I think the way I am doing is not optimal if this list is huge.

- How can I make this performance efficient?
- What is the better way to achieve the same result?

```
{
  "Lines": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "AccountingTotal": 10.2,
      "Description": "Description 1",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": "803"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "AccountingTotal": 10,
      "Description": "Description 2",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": "804"
    },
    {
      "Id": 3,
      "AccountingTotal": 10.2,
      "Description": "Description 3",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": "803"
    }
  ]
}
```

Desired List:

```
{
  "Lines": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "AccountingTotal": 20.4,
      "Description": "Description 1 | Description 3",
      "Price": "20.00",
      "Total": "20.00",
      "LineId": "803"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "AccountingTotal": 10,
      "Description": "Description 2",
      "Price": "10.00",
      "Total": "10.00",
      "LineId": "804"
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
public class Line
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // This should be combination of id. i.e., "1|2|3", etc.
    public string MergedId { get; set; }
    public decimal? AccountingTotal { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }
    public string LineId { get; set; }
}

// Data
var lines = new List<Line>
{
    new Line
    {
        Id = 1,
        AccountingTotal = (decimal?)10.2,
        Description = "Description 1",
        Price = "10.00",
        Total = "10.00",
        LineId = "803"
    },
    new Line
    {
        Id = 2,
        AccountingTotal = (decimal?)10.2,
        Description = "Description 2",
        Price = "10.00",
        Total = "10.00",
        LineId = "804"
    },
    new Line
    {
        Id = 3,
        Description = "Description 3",
        Price = "10.00",
        Total = "10.00",
        LineId = "803"
    }
};

var objNew = new List<Line>();
for (var i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    for (var j = i + 1; j < lines.Count; j++)
    {
        if (lines[i].LineId == lines[j].LineId)
        {
            lines[i].AccountingTotal += Math.Round(lines[i].AccountingTotal + lines[j].AccountingTotal, 2);
            lines[i].Price  = (Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Price) + Convert.ToDouble(lines[j].Price)).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            lines[i].Total = (Convert.ToDouble(lines[i].Total) + Convert.ToDouble(lines[j].Total)).ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            lines[i].Description += "|" + lines[j].Description;
        }
    }

    objNew.Add(lines[i]);
}

// Pick first out of many dup ids
var result = objNew.GroupBy(x => x.LineId).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: @DenisMicheal.k I am not sure. I need to do some calculation and modification on text.

Comment: I think in principle you want to first group by LineId, then do your "merge" on groups. I did not downvote, but I think using "merge" is a little bit too vague here - I may be wrong, but this is confusing your question with other "merge" questions. You were probably downvoted as a duplicate.

Comment: You could use a hashing structure such as a Dictionary.  Then you only have to loop through the list one time and at each line check if the dictionary contains the `lineId` and, if so, merge it.  This should in theory perform better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge is possible in... not so complex way.

If you can group "similar" `Line`'s just by LineId, then after grouping you can use `Aggregate` to sum up values from each other `Line` to first `Line` in group:

```
var groupedLines = lines.GroupBy(line => line.LineId)
                        .Select(linesGroup => linesGroup.Aggregate((firstLine, nextLine) =>
{
    // firstLine is first line in each group.
    // nextLine is second and other lines in same group
    // Aggregation uses first line as base and iterating through
    // each other line in group with code below (which sums properties)
  
    // Sum up Price
    if (double.TryParse(firstLine.Price, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var firstLinePrice) 
        && double.TryParse(nextLine.Price, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var nextLinePrice))
        firstLine.Price = (firstLinePrice + nextLinePrice).ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    // Sum up Total
    if (double.TryParse(firstLine.Total, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var firstLineTotal) 
        && double.TryParse(nextLine.Total, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out var nextLineTotal))
        firstLine.Total = (firstLineTotal + nextLineTotal).ToString("0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    // Sum up AccountingTotal
    firstLine.AccountingTotal = Math.Round(firstLine.AccountingTotal + nextLine.AccountingTotal, 2);
    // Concat Description
    firstLine.Description += " | " + nextLine.Description;

    return firstLine;
})).ToList();
```

Code looks like a mess because you store decimal values as strings and for "safe" conversion i used `TryParse`. It would be much shorter if you change `Price` and `Total` to `decimal` or `double`, even nullable.

I mean if you allowed to change properties types, you can minify code to that:

```
public class Line
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double AccountingTotal { get; set; }
    public string? Description { get; set; }
    public double? Price { get; set; }
    public double? Total { get; set; }
    public string? LineId { get; set; }

    public Line AddValuesFrom(Line other)
    {
        Price += other.Price;
        Total += other.Total;
        AccountingTotal += other.AccountingTotal;
        Description += $" | {other.Description}";

        return this;
    }
}

// ...

var lines = // new List<Line>(); or how you get them
var groupedLines = lines.GroupBy(line => line.LineId)
                   .Select(linesGroup => 
                       linesGroup.Aggregate((firstLine, nextLine) => 
                          firstLine.AddValuesFrom(nextLine)))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Here I have another property, `MergedId`, which should be a combination of `id`. How can I achieve that here? If I do `firstLine.MergedId = firstLine.Id + " | " + nextLine.Id;` then it just gives `1|3` but need `1|2|3` when all `LineId` are same. i.e, `803` in my sample data.

Comment: From your example how it can be `1|2|3` if only 2 same lines in group? If lines 1 and 3 merged - then `1|3` is correct result, why it should be `1|2|3`?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I was saying if I tweak that data where all LineId = 803, then. I found the solution by doing `firstLine.MergedId += string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstLine.MergedId)? firstLine.Id + " | " + nextLine.Id : " | " + nextLine.Id;`

Comment: Or you can create a separate model, `MergedLines` for example, which would store merged instances of `Line`. Similar to Regex `Match` and `MatchCollection`

Comment: Thank you. Now I am looking into the case where `AccountingTotal` is not present. Because it is nullable field. Right now, current logic breaks. i.e., in my sample data, 3rd object is missing that.

Comment: If you worry about possible null exception - you can secure yourself by editing property getter. Like `get => _accountingTotal.HasValue ? _accountingTotal.Value : 0;` (where _accountingTotal is backing field for your property, also of nullable type). This way you will receive 0 instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using grouping first, then the "merging" per your requirements:

```
var newLines = new List<Line>();
var grouped = lines.GroupBy(x => x.LineId);
foreach (var group in grouped) {
    newLines.Add(new Line
    {
        AccountingTotal = group.Select(c => c.AccountingTotal).Sum(),
        Description = string.Join("|", group.Select(c => c.Description)),
        Price = Math.Round(
            group.Select(c => Convert.ToDouble(c.Price)).Sum(), 2)
            .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        Total = Math.Round(
            group.Select(c => Convert.ToDouble(c.Total)).Sum(), 2)
            .ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
        LineId = group.Key
    });
}
```

Comment: here `Id` becomes 0 which I do not want. I want to retain values of properties I am not changing.

Comment: I was unsure what Id you want to keep ... can you explain that? For instance, in your original example you have Ids 1 and 3 both with lineId 803. You cannot "retain" the value of this property because it cannot be both 1 and 3. It could easily be made 1 OR 3 ... so you can keep the first id if that is your wish: `Id = group.Select(c => c.Id).First()`, or as with Description, `Id = string.Join("|", group.Select(c => c.Id.ToString()))`